# Read Field Label and Values From PDF and Extract To CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pdf, adobe

I am trying to extract a folder of PDF's along with the field name and values for each field into a CSV format. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
pdfobject=open('desktop.pdf','rb')
pdf=pypdf.PdfFileReader(pdfobject)
pdf.getFormTextFields()

pdf = pd.DataFrame(data)

pdf.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Kathryn\Desktop\export_dataframe.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

I've tried using this code but it only exports the field labes as 1, 2, and 3